# $ is not a function - jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the jQuery loaded fine, I've quadruple-checked, though I'm getting this error in FireBug "$ is not a function" and my code doesn't work.

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("ol li:nth-child(1)").addClass('olli1');
    $("ol li:nth-child(2)").addClass("olli2");
    $("ol li:nth-child(3)").addClass("olli3");
    $("ol li:nth-child(4)").addClass("olli4");
    $("ol li:nth-child(5)").addClass("olli5");
    $("ol li:nth-child(6)").addClass("olli6");
    $("ol li:nth-child(7)").addClass("olli7");
    $("ol li:nth-child(8)").addClass("olli8");
    $("ol li:nth-child(9)").addClass("olli9");
    $("ol li:nth-child(10)").addClass("olli10");
    $("ol li:nth-child(11)").addClass("olli11");
    $("ol li:nth-child(12)").addClass("olli12");
    $("ol li:nth-child(13)").addClass("olli13");
    $("ol li:nth-child(14)").addClass("olli14");
    $("ol li:nth-child(15)").addClass("olli15");
    $("ol li:nth-child(16)").addClass("olli16");
    $("ol li:nth-child(17)").addClass("olli17");
    $("ol li:nth-child(18)").addClass("olli18");
    $("ol li:nth-child(19)").addClass("olli19");
    $("ol li:nth-child(20)").addClass("olli20"); 
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery is loaded in the header and this script in the footer, so this is not the issue

Comment: HTML please?  Maybe a demo page?

Comment: what happens when you wrap this in `$(document).ready();`?

Comment: OffTopic: Wow! your going to have 20 different classes for a simple list? shouldn't you approach this in other way?

Comment: Haven't called [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) anywhere, have you?

Comment: Please post the smallest possible example in jsbin/jsfiddle where the error occurs, so we get even a little chance to help you. Just that short portion of code plus "... so this is not the issue" is the same as asking my crystal ball what the problem is...

Comment: demo page http://www.softsailor.com/how-to/46957-how-to-use-greenpois0n-to-jailbreak-iphone-4-3gs-ipad-ipod-touch-ios-4-14-0.html

Comment: What happens when you replace '$' with 'jQuery'?

Comment: I've also tried the $(document).ready(); and it doesn't work

Answer (score 191, accepted):

In Wordpress [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) is called on the jQuery file it includes (scroll to the bottom of the file it's including for jQuery to see this), **which means `$` doesn't work**, but `jQuery` does, so your code should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function($) {
    for(var i=0; i <= 20; i++) 
      $("ol li:nth-child(" + i + ")").addClass('olli' + i);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I've replaced my code with this one, but it still doesn't work. This is the page http://www.softsailor.com/how-to/46957-how-to-use-greenpois0n-to-jailbreak-iphone-4-3gs-ipad-ipod-touch-ios-4-14-0.html

Comment: @Alex - Taking a look, noConflict is definitely your issue with `$`...see it in your jQuery include at the end: http://www.softsailor.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.2, seeing what else is wrong now.

Comment: @Alex - You don't have the code in the answer, your code has `var i=i` for some reason, it should be `var i=0`, replace that and it'll work.

Comment: by making $ a function i was able to fix my code `var $ = jQuery;`

Comment: @sairfan then you'll get conflicts instead

Answer (score 50):

It's really hard to tell, but one of the 9001 ads on the page may be clobbering the `$` object.

jQuery provides the global `jQuery` object (which *is* present on your page).  You can do the following to "get" `$` back:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // Your code here
});
```

If you think you're having jQuery problems, please use the debug (non-production) versions of the library.

Also, it's probably not best to be editing a live site like that ...

Answer (score 7):

In my case I was using jquery on my typescript file:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
```

But that line gives me back an Object: `$` and it does not allow to use it as a function (I can not use `$('my-selector')`). I managed to solve my problem with the lines below. I hope they could help you guys:

```
import * as JQuery from "jquery";
const $ = JQuery.default;
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("ol li:nth-child(1)").addClass('olli1');
    $("ol li:nth-child(2)").addClass("olli2");
    $("ol li:nth-child(3)").addClass("olli3");
    $("ol li:nth-child(4)").addClass("olli4");
    $("ol li:nth-child(5)").addClass("olli5");
    $("ol li:nth-child(6)").addClass("olli6");
    $("ol li:nth-child(7)").addClass("olli7");
    $("ol li:nth-child(8)").addClass("olli8");
    $("ol li:nth-child(9)").addClass("olli9");
    $("ol li:nth-child(10)").addClass("olli10");
    $("ol li:nth-child(11)").addClass("olli11");
    $("ol li:nth-child(12)").addClass("olli12");
    $("ol li:nth-child(13)").addClass("olli13");
    $("ol li:nth-child(14)").addClass("olli14");
    $("ol li:nth-child(15)").addClass("olli15");
    $("ol li:nth-child(16)").addClass("olli16");
    $("ol li:nth-child(17)").addClass("olli17");
    $("ol li:nth-child(18)").addClass("olli18");
    $("ol li:nth-child(19)").addClass("olli19");
    $("ol li:nth-child(20)").addClass("olli20"); 
</script>
```

change this to

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $("ol li:nth-child(1)").addClass('olli1');
        $("ol li:nth-child(2)").addClass("olli2");
        $("ol li:nth-child(3)").addClass("olli3");
        $("ol li:nth-child(4)").addClass("olli4");
        $("ol li:nth-child(5)").addClass("olli5");
        $("ol li:nth-child(6)").addClass("olli6");
        $("ol li:nth-child(7)").addClass("olli7");
        $("ol li:nth-child(8)").addClass("olli8");
        $("ol li:nth-child(9)").addClass("olli9");
        $("ol li:nth-child(10)").addClass("olli10");
        $("ol li:nth-child(11)").addClass("olli11");
        $("ol li:nth-child(12)").addClass("olli12");
        $("ol li:nth-child(13)").addClass("olli13");
        $("ol li:nth-child(14)").addClass("olli14");
        $("ol li:nth-child(15)").addClass("olli15");
        $("ol li:nth-child(16)").addClass("olli16");
        $("ol li:nth-child(17)").addClass("olli17");
        $("ol li:nth-child(18)").addClass("olli18");
        $("ol li:nth-child(19)").addClass("olli19");
        $("ol li:nth-child(20)").addClass("olli20"); 
     });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6):

There are quite lots of answer based on situation.

1) Try to replace **'$'** with **"jQuery"**

2) Check that code you are executed are always below the main jquery script.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

});
</script>
```

3) Pass $ into the function and add "jQuery" as a main function like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

As RPM1984 refers to, this is mostly likely caused by the fact that your script is loading before jQuery is loaded.

Comment: jQuery is loaded in the header and this script in the footer, so this is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

That error kicks in when you have forgot to include the jQuery library in your page or there is conflict between libraries - for example you be using any other javascript library on your page.

Take a look at this for more info:

- [Using jQuery with other libraries](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries)

Answer (score 1):

When jQuery is not present you get `$ is undefined` and not your message.

Did you check if you don't have a variable called $ somewhere before your code?
Inspect the value of $ in firebug to see what it is.

Slightly out of the question, but I can't resist to write a shorter code to your class assignment:

```
    var i = 1;
    $("ol li").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('olli' + i++);
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

Use jQuery for $. I tried and work.

Answer (score -2):

I believe using $ alone is now deprecated in the new version of jQuery. Use below syntax instead:

```
jQuery(function($) {
//magic here
})
```

Answer (score -4):

There are two possible reasons for that error:

1. your jquery script file referencing is not valid
2. try to put your jquery code in document.ready, like this:

   $(document).ready(function(){

   ....your code....

   });

cheers

Comment: The jQuery is included automatically by Wordpress. I tried that and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think the use of, or non-use of the document ready construct would make any difference at all here.  Also, if '$' isn't yet defined, how can you call $(document.ready(...) ?  Sorry, -1.