# How can I set location for a button on-click event using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have this page:

[link](http://dgprint.dg-site.com/)

Here on the homepage, you will find a button called "Get a quote". When you click on this button I want to open link "google.com".

I tried to do this with jQuery using this code but it's not working.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
    window.location = "www.google.com/index.php?id=";
    });
});
```

This site is made with Wordpress and I used the plugin Contact Form 7

```
<div class="contact-frm">
        <div class="right">
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="9" title="get a quote"]'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Can you please help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe `$('.wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-submit')`?

Answer (score 4):

You forgot two things:

1. Add a `http://` in front of the URL.
2. Change `wpcf7-submit` to `.wpcf7-submit`.

Use this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
        window.location = "http://www.google.com/index.php?id=" + $(this).attr("id");
    });
});
```

Comment: I added this code but do not understand why not go now ... if I click on the button does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

use the below code:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/index.php?id=";
```

adding `http://` before the link can help you.

Also use:

```
$('.wpcf7-form-control .wpcf7-submit');
```

if `wpcf7-submit` is class specify it using dot `.` in jQuery

if `wpcf7-submit` is id then specify it using dot `#` in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit').click(function() {
        window.location = "www.google.com/index.php?id=";
    });
});
```

Use this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(function($) {
        $(".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit").click(function() {
            window.location = "http://www.google.com/index.php?id=";
        });
    });
});
```

It will work for you. There is something you should know:

- In jquery selector you should write two classas without space
- `$` doesn't work in wordpress, For more information see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3931680/4497248)

Comment: I added this code but do not understand why not go now ... if I click on the button does not change anything

Comment: @Gigi Do you add this code inside of (document).ready()?
I will update my answer, wait a second