# Ajax form submission uncaught error when click on submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to process data in popup as ajax and display successful message inside popup only, Nothing is happening when I click on 'Submit An Offer' button, in console logs I saw uncaught error.

Popup Modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?php echo esc_html($post->ID);?>" data-whatever="@getbootstrap">Submit Offer</button>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?php echo esc_html($post->ID);?>" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Submit Your Offer for <?php echo esc_html($post->post_title);?></h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <p class="statusMsg"></p>
        <form role="form">
     <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-md-12"  for="Name"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Name', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
            <input  class="col-md-12" id="name" name="name" type="text" required>
         <imput type="hidden" id="id" value="<?php $post->ID ?>">
     </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Email', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
             <input class="col-md-12"  id="email" type="text" required>
     </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="price" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Price', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
             <input class="col-md-12"  id="price" type="number" required>
     </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="purchase_type" class="col-md-12"><?php  esc_html_e( 'Purchase Type', 'ivproperty' ); ?><span class="red-star">*</span></label>
<select class="col-md-12" id="purchase_type" required>
  <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
  <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
  <option value="Conventional Loan">Conventional Loan</option>
  <option value="FHA Loan">FHA Loan</option>
  <option value="MSHDA Conventional Loan">MSHDA Conventional Loan</option>
  <option value="MSHDA FHA Loan">MSHDA FHA Loan</option>
  <option value="Land Contract">Land Contract</option>
</select>
     </div>
 <div class="modal-footer">                 
                                        
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary submitBtn" onclick="submitContactForm()">Submit An Offer</button>
                        </div>  
</form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <?php echo esc_html($post->ID);?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>
function submitContactForm(){
    var reg = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@([A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var price = $('#price').val();
    var purchase_type = $('#purchase_type').val();
    var id = $('#id').val();
    if(name.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your name.');
        $('#inputName').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() == '' ){
        alert('Please enter your email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    }else if(email.trim() != '' && !reg.test(email)){
        alert('Please enter valid email.');
        $('#inputEmail').focus();
        return false;
    }else{
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/submitoffer.php',
            data:'OfferSubmit=1&name='+name+'&email='+email+'&price='+price+'&purchase_type='+purchase_type+'&id='+id,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled","disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '.5');
            },
            success:function(msg){
                if(msg == 'ok'){
                    $('#name').val('');
                    $('#email').val('');
                    $('#price').val('');
                    $('#purchase_type').val('');
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:green;">Offer Submitted Successfully.</p>');
                }else{
                    $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="color:red;">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                }
                $('.submitBtn').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('.modal-body').css('opacity', '');
            }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

Error I'm seeing in console log:
[image]

What I want is when user open's popup and fill the form and then submit it, data should get processed inside popup only and display the status result.

[This question doesn't answer my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931529) as pop-up modal stopped working after applying solution provided in a little similar question.

Comment: Did you import jquery? I don't see it in your HTML

Comment: thanks for reply, Yes I am using wordpress and JQuery is imported, popup is working  fine but this form submission is not doing anything.

Comment: Are you sure? `$ is not a function` usually means jQuery isn't loaded. If you're sure, are you using any other conflicting libraries (MooTools for example)? You can wrap your code inside a `jQuery.noConflict` to prevent conflicts if so.

Comment: I deregistered default wordpress JQuery and added `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js` in header.

but pop-up stopped working, popup is not coming up, getting error when clicking on pop-up trigger button:
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement':

Comment: [Pop Up Error Screenshot](https://paste.pics/0e629052b083aedf373891a99be1208d)

Comment: @qazidev You are using jquery v1.12.4. The 3.1.1 is never loaded

Comment: I did it using custom code in functions.php also checked source code.

Comment: [Please do not post images of code/error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).  Copy-paste the relevant parts of your error msg and add them to your question.

Comment: Did you try searching for your error msg? There are many duplicates here on SO, with many solutions, have you tried all of those?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$ is not a function - jQuery error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931529/is-not-a-function-jquery-error)

Comment: @Don'tPanic no it doesn't answer my question that's why I created question, please try to help

Comment: So you have tried everything suggested in that question?  Eg using `jQuery` instead of `$`, and putting your code inside `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {`?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your function inside this:

```
$(function() {
 // your code here
});
```

Or this:

```
(function( $ ) {
 // your code here
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: Thanks, can you just modify my code and edit in your answer, I am getting confused.

Comment: I don't see how this answer should fix the OP's problem. The indication is clearly that jQuery has not been loaded correctly.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen jquery could be loaded internally in a different js, it is not said that if it is not seen in the console it is not loaded.

Comment: @qazidev example:
(function( $ ) {
function submitContactForm(){...}
} )( jQuery );

Same for other test.

Comment: @Michela-Durazzi I tried but still facing same issue.

Comment: @qazidev I'm sorry, then you should show us your site, so we don't try to

Comment: definitely you can go to my site and click on Submit offer button to check or check source code:
[check page click here](https://submitalloffers.stagingweb.net/properties/)

Comment: jQuery is loaded.
First error I see is this block:
<script>$('#exampleModal4179').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {...})</script>
All of this code must be inserted in one of my example above.
Like this:
(function( $ ) { $('#exampleModal4179').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {...}) } )( jQuery );
Please change it, then I refresh and see if it resolves first error.

Comment: thanks, I added modal code inside `$(function() { });` as you instructed, can you please refresh and check.

Comment: no, the code I write in last comment (function( $ ) ... it's the second of my first example

Comment: When I put modal script in `(function( $ ) { } )( jQuery );` popup stopped working, can you please check now.

Comment: Now the code is executed, so this is the right solution.
Let's move on to the next problem.
Please comment these two lines, I think the error is here:
// modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
// modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
The comment is only used for identify the lines with errors.