# How to link a url to a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am using a WordPress website and trying to attach a url to a button using JavaScript. I have written a function to this, My function as follows.

```
<div class="the_course_button" data-id="3565"><div class="course_button full button"><a href="https://gutsycreatives.com/course/writing-game-gala/?renew">TAKE THIS COURSE</a></div></div>

  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $('#3565').each(function() {
  var link = $(this).html();
  $(this).contents().wrap('<a href="https://gutsycreatives.com/product/writing-game-gala/"></a>');
 });
});
```

I passed my data-id '#3565' to call the function. Now I am getting nothing

What did I do wrong here?

I appreciate the help thanks so much.

Comment: Do you want the url to open after clicking the button ?

Comment: you are using jquery & probably you have not included it.

Comment: your  selector is wrong - you have nothing with an id of 3565 (also ids are meant to be unique so there's no point doing `.each` on it) but your error is pointing to the fact you don't have jquery loaded

Comment: @VishalSharma Yes I want the url to open after clicking the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That syntax you are using, is from JQuery, so the error you are getting, is problably because you haven't linked it correctly.

If you want to use `JavaScript` For making this, you should use `document.getElementById("3565")`

You will need to change more things if you want to use JavScript, but if you need to use JQuery, you should look this link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clarify clearly on which environment you get that error.
Since I see your tag 'wordpress' so I assume you get the error in wordpress.
If so, please read this reference: [$ is not a function - jQuery error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931529/is-not-a-function-jquery-error)
Your code should be wrapped like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $('#3565').each(function() {
  var link = $(this).html();
  $(this).contents().wrap('<a href="https://gutsycreatives.com/product/writing-game-gala/"></a>');
 });
});
```